# Why does ux.stackexchange crash safari?

Tags: bug, support

I've been using ux.stackexchange daily using Safari on Max OS X (Mountain Lion) and since yesterday Safari just crashes as soon as ux.stackexhange finishes loading.

What has changed or is anyone else experiencing this?

I had to use Chrome to come and post this.

Comment: Cannot reproduce on 10.8.1 and Safari 6.0.. do you have any plugins or add-ons installed?

Comment: No plugins. I'll try to figure out what has changed before it starting crashing. All other websites are running fine, just ux stackexchange. Very weird.

Comment: Relevant MSO post: [Safari 6 crashing when accessing Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141615)

Answer (score 2):

I figured out what is going on. When it crashes I am working on location at a client where we have web access through a proxy. When I'm at home or homebase with no proxy it doesn't crash so they must be running something that causes the crash - which seems a bit strange.

Answer (score 1):

Likely it's some sort of middle-ware traffic analyzer (like [netflow](http://www.manageengine.com/products/netflow/cisco-netflow.html)), that usually injects little pictures, comments and warnings, that is (unintentionally) [corrupting certain types of traffic](http://www.plixer.com/blog/network-traffic-analysis/netflow-collection-what-is-packet-loss/).

**It's relatively common with ANY sort of network device, and Cisco is one of the bigger providers.**

The traffic is (as you mentioned) usually routed through a proxy, to ensure ALL browser traffic is analyzed.